# In C# how do I get Conventions from Context object in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, conventions

I would like to get Conventions that were created on OnModelCreating, from my context object.

Example:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{

    public MyContext(): base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString)
    {
        
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<DecimalPropertyConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DecimalPropertyConvention(18, 8));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

In this example, I would like to get DecimalPropertyConvention from my context.

```
var context = new MyContext();
var conventions = context.GetConventions(); ///Just to exemplify.
```

I'm using EF 6.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's probably much easier to store the conventions you add in a private member variable. Why do you need to know them later?

Comment: Hi, Gert, because I'm creating custom Temporary Tables, and would like to get this information to create decimal columns with exactly same size.

Comment: It's easier anyway to store what you need in a little structure yourself. Even if you can list the conventions you can't do much with them because hardly anything in them is public. It would take tons of awkward reflection.